# spring boot security exception messages localization

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to use other language for spring security exception messages. Refer to below document, I created messageSource but it doesn't work.

Anyone can help please? thanks in advance.

```
java_version=11
spring_boot_version=2.5.0 (with spring security: version 5.2.8)
spring_dependency_management_version=1.0.11.RELEASE
javax_validation_version=2.0.1.Final
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#localization

```
Request Header:
Accept-Language: zh
```

The Response is always in English, not Chinese.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-05-27T14:00:46.098+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Bad credentials",
    "path": "/api/login"
}
```

LocaleConfig source code as follows. this works for JPA validation but not for spring security exception message.

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfig {


    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.addBasenames("classpath:locales/messages", "classpath:org/springframework/security/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver resolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        resolver.setSupportedLocales(Arrays.asList(Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.CHINESE));
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by implement authenticationEntryPoint. As I am using jwt authentication. below are the solutions in HttpSecurity config.

```
// Set unauthorized requests exception handler
    http = http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(
            (request, response, ex) -> {
                if (ex instanceof BadCredentialsException)
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                            messageSource.getMessage("error.authentication.badCredentials", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
                else if (ex instanceof InsufficientAuthenticationException)
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                            messageSource.getMessage("error.authentication..noAuthority", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
                else
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
    ).and();
```